# Is there a way to set my image URLs to my node server url instead of my CD instance

Tags: sxa, media-library

So I havent been able to track down a article of how you change the name of my images coming out of my media library. The mynewsite is the site running my node server calling my prod-cd content.
Example:
https://prod-us.sitecoretree.com/-/media/images/project/common/logos/2019-logo.ashx
and I need them to resolve but I want my URL to be
https://www.mynewsite.com/-/media/images/project/common/logos/2019-logo.ashx or I guess I could just have it set as
/-/media/images/project/common/logos/2019-logo.ashx
Almost like a virtual directory type of setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be basically the same as using a CDN. There is a config file for this in **App_Config/Include/Examples/CDN.config.example** Basically, the settings you are looking for are:

- **Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl**: Ensures that all media links will always include the full server URL
- **Media.MediaLinkServerUrl**: Specifies what the server URL (including the scheme and hostname) should be for all media links

The rest of the settings in **CDN.Config.example** are probably not necessary for your use case, but may be necessary. They are documented in that config.

**Note**: Make sure you always use built-in methods for retrieving media URLs, or else you won't be leveraging this functionality, and all bets will be off at that point.

Comment: Yeah I have tried this and its a great option and worked. Was able to change the URL name however the images didnt render because of the proxy I believe. I was trying to see if it would just remove the starting part and just have this -/media/images/project/common/logos/2019-logo.ashx but that didnt work. Only the server url makes it show.